# Applying child element background color to parent's padding

Tags: css, padding, background-color

Basically I'm trying to achieve this: 
[image]

But I'm currently dealing with this:
[image]

I want to fill the element's parents padding. But stuck on how to do so.

Here's my HTML and CSS

```css
    .form-group {
        margin: auto;
        width: 50%;
        border: 1px solid lightgrey;
        padding: 15px;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    h4 {
        font-weight: 400;
        background-color: #0c234b;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
    <div className="form-group">
        <h4>Contact Information</h4>
    </div>
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Just apply `padding: 20px` to h4?

Comment: Something like this?: https://jsfiddle.net/01ra6mLs/

Comment: @ManojKumar That still leaves a white padding around it.

Comment: One way to avoid this problem is by not adding padding to the parent at all. Just add a uniform padding to each child element that you want to have it.

Comment: You're really trying to position the child element at the top of parent, not apply the child background color to parent's padding. The accepted answer does this with a negative top margin on the child.

Comment: @ChrisSandvik That seems rather tedious though, no?

Comment: I posted an answer highlighting my idea.  It doesn't have to be tedious if you just section the content off into its own container and deal with the padding directly on that.  Structuring your code this way will save you headaches in the future, I swear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to deal with this problem is to not have it happen in the first place.  It is better to avoid dealing with negative margins if they're not necessary as they make your code confusing.

My recommendation is instead of adding padding to the form itself, section your form off into a header and body section and handle their padding values individually.  That way, structure of your css makes a bit more sense.

```css
.form {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.form-header {
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: #0c234b;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

.form-content {
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.form-row {
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <h4 class="form-header">Contact Information</h4>
  <div class="form-content">
    <div class="form-row">
      <label>label</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <label>label</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <label>label</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <label>label</label>
      <input type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Appreciate you taking the time to write this out, thank you.

Comment: No problem!  glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

Try changing in the h4

`margin-bottom: 20px;`

to

`margin: -15px -15px 20px -15px;`

This should negate the `15px` padding on the parent wrapper

```css
.form-group {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

h4 {
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: #0c234b;
  margin: -15px -15px 20px -15px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div className="form-group">
  <h4>Contact Information</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks so much, adding this to my toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Apply border-radius to header div
- Create empty div that will fill in the bottom left/right corners of the header and will also leave the bottom of the header straight.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: slategrey;
  padding: 10px;
}


/* IMPORTANT STYLES BELOW */

.container {
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 280px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* Border Radius on container div */
}

.header {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  border-radius: 3px;
  /* Border Radius on header div */
  padding: 3px;
}

.header-title {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


/* Backdrop div used to fill in the bottom left/right corners with the header background color */

.backdrop {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  height: 4px;
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <h2 class="header-title">Contact Information</h2>
  </div>
  <!-- Backdrop div used to cover bottom left/right corners of the header with the header background color -->
  <div class="backdrop"></div>
</div>
```